# Twilio push notification Webhook validation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, push-notification, twilio, authy

Has anyone experience with this subject?
On the Twilio docs, while there are several C# snippets for every step, this one has been completely missed:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/authy/validation
It's the last step in a Twilio Authy push notification chain, where on the server you have a webhook and should validate integrity of incoming POST from Twilio.
Exemples for this step are only node and ruby. I tried to convert to C# but the steps for key verification are many and complex that just a wrong char will mess up the final checksum result.
Does any of you already have this code working in production with C#?
I made everything work, but I'm not validating X-Authy-Signature in the last step so at the moment I'm not using it.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why are you using older methods? Authy has been deprecated. That's why there are no recent examples.

Comment: Thank you Andy for the reply... so from what I understand at the moment Twilio doesn't offer a supported/developed push/otp two factor authentication service anymore?

Comment: Twilio has a nuget package you can install that takes care of everything for you. Here is an example on how to use it: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api

Comment: Hallo Andy thanks again for your reply but the new Verify API from twilio only supports codes sent via voice, SMS, and email.
So it seems they discontinued somehow Authy but have no alternatives for TOTP and Push notifications